# Facebook Graph API: manage app roles

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, roles

I want to manage Facebook [app roles using the graph API,](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/app/roles) basically to add another admins programmatically.

I'm experimenting with the open graph explorer right now, with a `manage_pages` permission (there is not `manage_apps`, so I guess that this is the appropriate one), with the account that created that app (and its sole admin for now), but I get the following error: `(#100) Only the owner of the app may perform this operation.`

[image: graph explorer output]

Any idea of what might be going on here? Because after the feature to use groups for roles was deprecated, I start feeling like Facebook actively wants to difficult any cooperative app management...

Comment: I think you need to use an app access token.

Comment: nope, that's for reading the roles, if you use an app token when POSTing, you get a different error...

Comment: @WizKid I just tried again with the app token and the error is the same (I would have swore it was a different one), but the documentation clearly says "A user access token for any admin of the app is required."

Comment: Then I'm guessing that the access token you are using don't have admin rights. If it does file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Answer (score 1):

I realized that the user access token has to be generated for the app that you are trying to manage rather than for the Graph Explorer app (application drop down on the top).